# Laravel 4 Migration error - creates two auto_increment primary keys fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I made a migration with this setup:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id', 10)->unsigned(); // this is meant to be used as a foreign key
```

After doing php artisan migrate it returns an error:

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                                                                 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition;
there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `transactions` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci) (Bindings: array ())
```

I didn't specify user_id to be an auto_increment primary key but Migration treats it as so.

How can I make a foreign key in Migrations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@crynobone: Second parameter are for boolean use to determine primary key, there no length option for integer.

Refer here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2212#issuecomment-21608193

Comment: So how do you deal with foreign keys?

Comment: nvm, found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077573/laravel-migration-will-not-add-foreign-key you should use $table->integer('app_group_id')->length(10)->unsigned(); in Laravel 4

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 4 , second parameter in integer function is for indicating the integer column to be auto incremented or not ( and therefore primary key or not ) 
In my case , to add an auto incremented id in a table I write it like that

```
$table->integer('id' , true);
```

It creates an integer column with 11 digits .

Answer (score -2):

Why not specify `user_id` as primary key with autoincrement?

```
$table->increments('user_id');
// other columns
...
```

Schema builder create `user_id`, which is 10 digits long, unsigned & primary key.