# Laravel migration will not add foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to migrations and attempting to create 2 tables with a foreign key in one referencing an id in the other but I am getting a general failure to add key error. is there something I am missing?

error:

`[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

code:

```
    Schema::create('app_groups', function($table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('app_name');
     $table->unsignedInteger('app_group_id');
     $table->timestamps();
  });

  Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->unsignedInteger('app_group_id');
     $table->unsignedInteger('bucket_id');
     $table->timestamps();
  });
  Schema::table('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->foreign('app_group_id')->references('app_group_id')->on('app_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

Comment: Why aren't you adding the foreign key when the table was created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

The issue was that Laravel automatically assumes incrementing columns as the primary key. so I needed to specify that my `app_group_id` was the primary key.

```
 Schema::create('app_groups', function($table) {
     $table->string('app_name');
     $table->integer('app_group_id');
     $table->primary('app_group_id');
     $table->timestamps();
  });

  Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->integer('app_group_id');
     $table->integer('bucket_id');
      $table->primary('bucket_id');
     $table->timestamps();
  });
  Schema::table('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->foreign('app_group_id')->references('app_group_id')->on('app_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

Answer (score 18):

This will work for sure. Eloquent primary keys are integer with length 10 and unsigned. This is why the relation is not working.

```
Schema::create('app_groups', function($table) {
     $table->string('app_name');
     $table->integer('app_group_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
     $table->timestamps();
  });

  Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->integer('app_group_id');
     $table->integer('bucket_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
     $table->timestamps();
  });
  Schema::table('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->foreign('app_group_id')->references('app_group_id')->on('app_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Looking more carefylly, the documentation says: "Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned."

(ref: http://laravel.com/docs/schema)

Comment: Just curious, what's the default length for an integer? Is the length(10) part necessary?

Comment: The default length for the integer in MySQL is 11 but in Laravel it is 10. I do not know why. Maybe there is a reason. It got to work without lenght(10). But I am using it just for any case.

Comment: I googled this problem like for 5 hours and finally found your solution that saved my day thank you

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are several problems you could meet while creating/adding foreign key constraints in MySQL-databases using Laravel.

First of all, you should check names of column's and table's you assign.

Secondly, check the **database engine** while creating the constraint. 
Refer to documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html it should be **InnoDB**.

```
Schema::create('app_groups', function($table) {
     // setting up the storage engine
     $table->engine='InnoDB';
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('app_name');
     $table->timestamps();
  });

Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->engine='InnoDB';
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('app_group_id')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('bucket_id')->unsigned();
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->foreign('app_group_id')
           ->references('group_id')
           ->on('app_groups')
           ->onDelete('cascade');
})
;}
```

Thirdly(optional), move your assigment of constraints(foreign keys, indexes and so on) to **separate migration**.

Comment: The tables were being created as MyISAM and that was the problem. Setting InnoDB solves problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You must first create the table, then create the foreign keys:

```
Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('bucket_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('app_group_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('app_group_id')->references('app_group_id')->on('app_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and got the same error...updated the code above

Comment: Just don't create the column, it will be added by your database server. Edited.

Comment: I tried removing that line and it throws an error saying 'app_group_id' doesn't exist in table

Comment: Which database is this? Try to use unsigned() as in my last edit.

Comment: Odd, should work. Here's another accepted answer about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999161/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1005-cant-create-table-laravel-4/20999312#20999312.

Comment: i think the issue is that the field I am referencing is not an autoincrementing field.

Answer (score 1):

foreign key and reference key should have same length and same type. if you set those keys satisfying that, the error will not popup :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Schema::create('app_groups', function($table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('app_name');
     $table->timestamps();
  });
 Schema::create('app_to_bucket', function($table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('app_group_id')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('bucket_id')->unsigned();
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->foreign('app_group_id')->references('group_id')->on('app_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

Comment: ahh i was mistaken this will not work...I need the app_group_id to be able to repeat it cannot be incrementing. can be multiple app_names with the same app_group_id

Comment: I added the 'group_id' to 'app_groups'. I have nearly the exact same code on my app and it works fine.

Comment: I copy pasted this exactly and it does not work. it works fine when i try to reference the incrementing id but not the group_id

Comment: You could try wrapping your code in:

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
//code here
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

and see what happens